# Remove special characters from the string in java without regular expression

Tags: java, string

I want to create a method named trim.
The input string.
Get the string and remove all characters except A-Z and a-z and 0-9.
Example:

```
String Trim("a(9d%z)");
```

output:

> a9dz

This is the code that I wrote:

```
   void Trimming(String arg1){
        String resource = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTYZ";
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(arg1);
        for (int i = 0; i<arg1.length() ; i++) {
            for (int j =0;j< resource.length();j++){
                if(arg1.charAt(i) != resource.charAt(j) ){
                    b.deleteCharAt(j);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

use my method:

> r.Trimming("0%asd");

But the problem came :

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:797)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.deleteCharAt(StringBuilder.java:253)
    at Reshte.Trimming(Reshte.java:67)
    at Reshte.main(Reshte.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: I do not want to use regular expressions!please help

Comment: If the characters contained within the 'resource' variable are indeed a template of allowable characters then you can use just one for/loop. Simply iterate through the characters in arg1 as you are but instead of iterating through characters in resource just use: String c = Character.toString(arg1.charAt(i));  if(resource.contains(c)) { b+= c; }

Comment: use the debugger of your IDE, and step through the loop, one iteration at a time.